A proof of Springer-Steinberg theorem
So, Springer-Steinberg theorem is a result saying that nilpotent orbits in $\mathfrak{so}_{2n}$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the partitions in $n$ where even parts occur with even multiplicities. This was proved originally in a talk given by Springer-Steinberg at some conference (which is the reason Collingwood McGovern's "Nilpotent Orbits" call this theorem that name, more common name is simply Nilpotent orbits in $D_n$. I have seen back in time somewhere the entire book (with all the talks from that conference) but now I am not able to find it. Can someone just type name of the book and authors, please?

OK, should anyone else be needing this, the book is
Seminar of Algebraic Groups and Related Finite Groups, Lecture Notes in Mathematics, Springer-Verlag, 1970.
and the talk is
Springer, Steinberg "Conjugacy Classes".
